# Mysql get all data from table and count of some columns

Tags: mysql

have table `table 1` structure like:

```
`id, rma_id, order_id, product_id, order_nr, comment, admin_comment, add_date`
```

and data of it:

```
(40, 1, 110331, 4399, 1, 'comment1', '', '2016-09-30 08:46:54'),
(42, 2, 110331, 4399, 1, 'comment2', '', '2016-09-30 11:18:06'),
(43, 3, 110374, 4399, 1, 'comment3', '', '2016-10-03 05:55:25'),
(44, 4, 110374, 4399, 1, 'comment4', '', '2016-10-03 05:55:43'),
(45, 4, 110374, 4399, 2, 'comment5', '', '2016-10-03 05:55:43');
```

Using query like this to get all that of exact RMA:

```
SELECT * FROM `rma_products` WHERE `rma_id` = 4
```

and getting result like this:

```
[0] => array(8) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "44"
    ["rma_id"] => string(1) "4"
    ["order_id"] => string(6) "110374"
    ["product_id"] => string(4) "4399"
    ["order_nr"] => string(1) "1"
    ["comment"] => string(16) "comment4"
    ["admin_comment"] => string(0) ""
    ["add_date"] => string(19) "2016-10-03 08:55:43"
}
[1] => array(8) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "45"
    ["rma_id"] => string(1) "4"
    ["order_id"] => string(6) "110374"
    ["product_id"] => string(4) "4399"
    ["order_nr"] => string(1) "2"
    ["comment"] => string(7) "comment5"
    ["admin_comment"] => string(0) ""
    ["add_date"] => string(19) "2016-10-03 08:55:43"
}
```

but I want to add one more field like count that my result would be  like this:

```
[0] => array(8) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "44"
    ["rma_id"] => string(1) "4"
    ["order_id"] => string(6) "110374"
    ["product_id"] => string(4) "4399"
    ["order_nr"] => string(1) "1"
    ["comment"] => string(16) "comment4"
    ["admin_comment"] => string(0) ""
    ["add_date"] => string(19) "2016-10-03 08:55:43"
    ["count"] => string(1) "2"
}
[1] => array(8) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "45"
    ["rma_id"] => string(1) "4"
    ["order_id"] => string(6) "110374"
    ["product_id"] => string(4) "4399"
    ["order_nr"] => string(1) "2"
    ["comment"] => string(7) "comment5"
    ["admin_comment"] => string(0) ""
    ["add_date"] => string(19) "2016-10-03 08:55:43"
    ["count"] => string(1) "2"
}
```

which would be counted by how many same product_id is in same rma_id

Comment: I don't see how the counts are two for `44` and `45` using your sample data.

Comment: 2 because the rma_id is 4 and product_id is 4399.. but product_id could be different.. thats why need to get count of same product_id in same rma_id

Comment: To ask bluntly: how should we be aggregating your data to generate counts?  This is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.*,s.cnt from t
join
(select rma_id,product_id,count(*) cnt from t where rma_id = 4 group by rma_id,product_id) s 
on s.rma_id = t.rma_id and t.product_id = s.product_id
```